# IntelliJ Idea Cannot find sbt-idea-compiler-indices

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt-plugin

Installed IntelliJ Idea CE 2019.1 (on Win64, Windows 7 and 10, from zip) - and in both cases it cannot find the dependency shown below, so it cannot import an sbt project.

The project is valid, i.e. it compiles using sbt on the command line.

I am trying to import the project by opening build.sbt "as a project", something which usually works.

I am able to import this same project using Idea 2018.3 - so it sounds like something changed in the sbt plugin in 2019.1

I am working behind a firewall, but I have configured the proxy and checked that it can connect to outside repositories.

There is no mention of "sbt-idea-compiler-indices" in the log, and I see messages showing that Idea is downloading files from the outside.

```
sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.jetbrains#sbt-idea-compiler-indices;0.1.3: not found
```

Any idea what this means, or where I can find this dependency?

If all else fails, I could download the files manually and set them up under ~/.ivy2

```
[warn]          org.jetbrains:sbt-idea-compiler-indices:0.1.3 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]            +- org.scala-sbt:global-plugins:0.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sbt-compiler-indices is an sbt plugin that is distributed with the IntelliJ Scala plugin. Usually it will be resolved from disk, but in some setups this fails, for example when starting sbt with the `override.build.repos=true` option. This should be fixed soon when it is added to the main `sbt-plugin-releases` repo.

As a workaround, it should work if you start sbt from IntelliJ without the `override.build.repos=true` option once, so that the plugin can resolve into the cache.

See also: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-15261